# Hide html5 video on pause jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have an html5 video that is intitally hidden then revealed and played with a custom play button. However, on the iphone, when the user clicks "Done" from the video viewing screen, the video remains visible. I'm pretty sure the "done" button is a pause function. Assuming this to be the case, is there a way is there a way I can hide the video on pause on mobile only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
$("video")[0].addEventListener("webkitendfullscreen", function () {
            //hide video here
            $(this).hide();
        }, true);
```

The webkitendfullscreen event gets fired when the done button is pressed.

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you so much. I wish I could upvote this 30 times.